# Java array display is cut short

Tags: java, arrays, output

I've typed up a Java program that calculates arrays of grades for students.
The problem is that only one of the data sets is printed to screen, namely the grades for student 10.
I'm looking to print all the grades for all the students.

Any idea what would remedy this?

Here's the code:

```
 public class SummariseGrades
 {
 public static void main (String[]args)
 {
    //2d array of student grades
    int [][] gradesArray =
    { { 87,96,70 },
      { 68,87,90 },
      { 94,100,90 },
      { 100,81,82},
      { 83,65,85},
      { 78,87,85},
      { 85,75,83},
      { 91,94,100},
      { 76,72,84},
      { 87,93,73}  };

    //output grades array
    outputGrades ( gradesArray );

    //call methods getMinimum and getMaximum
    System.out.printf ("\n %s %d \n %s %d \n \n",
    "Lowest grade is", getMinimum ( gradesArray ),
    "Highest grade is", getMaximum (gradesArray ) ) ;

    //output grade distribution chart of all grades on all tests
    outputBarChart (gradesArray);

} //end main





//find minimum grade
public static int getMinimum (int grades [][])
{
    //assume first element of grades array is the minumum
    int lowGrade = grades [0][0];

    //loop through rows of grades array
    for (int [] studentGrades : grades )
    {
        //loop throught the columns of current row
        for (int grade : studentGrades )
        {
            //if grade less than lowGrade, assign it to lowGrade
            if (grade < lowGrade)
            lowGrade = grade ;
        } //end inner
    }//end outer

    return lowGrade;  // returns lowest grade
} //end method getMinimum





//find maximum grade
public static int getMaximum (int grades [][])
{
    //assume first element is the largest in array
    int highGrade = grades [0][0];

    //loop through rows of the grades array
    for (int[] studentGrades : grades)
    {
        //loop through columns of the current row
        for (int grade: studentGrades)
        {
            //if grade greater than highGrade then assign it to highGrade
            if (grade > highGrade)
            highGrade = grade;
        } //end inner
    } //end outer

    return highGrade;  // return highest grade

} //end method getMaximum



//determine average grade for particular set of grades
public static double getAverage (int[] setOfGrades )
{
    int total = 0;  // initialise total

    //sum grades for one student
    for (int grade : setOfGrades)
    total += grade;

    //return average of grades
    return (double) total / setOfGrades.length;
} //end method for getAverage



//output bar chart displaying overall grade distribution
public static void outputBarChart (int grades[][])
{
    System.out.println ("Overall grade distribution:");

    //stores the frequency of grades in each range of 10 grades
    int[] frequency = new int [11];

    // for each grade in the grade book, increment the appropriate frequency
    for (int [] studentGrades : grades)
    {
        for (int grade : studentGrades)
        ++frequency [ grade / 10 ];
    } //end outer

    //for each grade freq, print bar in chart
    for (int count = 0 ; count < frequency.length ; count++)
    {
        //output bar label
        if (count ==10)
        System.out.printf ( "%5d: ", 100);

        else
            System.out.printf ("%02d-%02d: ",
            count * 10, count * 10 + 9 );

        //print bar of asterisks
        for (int stars = 0 ; stars < frequency [ count ] ; stars++)
            System.out.print ("*");

        System.out.println();  //start a new line of output

    } //end outer for loop

} //end method for outputBarChart



//output contents of the grades array

public static void outputGrades ( int grades [][])
{
    System.out.println ("The grades are:\n");
    System.out.print ("               "); //align column heads

    // create a column heading for each of the tests
    for (int test = 0 ; test < grades [0].length; test ++)
        System.out.printf ("Test %d ", test + 1);

        System.out.println ("Average");  //student average column heading

    //create rows and columns of text representing array grades

  for (int student = 0 ; student < grades.length ; student ++)
  {
    System.out.printf ("Student %2d", student + 1);

    for ( int test : grades [ student ] ) // output student grades
        System.out.printf ("%8d", test );

    // call method getAverage to calculate the student's average grade
    // pass row of grades as the argument to getAverage
    double average = getAverage (grades [ student ] ) ;
    System.out.printf ("%9.2f \r", average );

    } // end outer for
 } // end method outputGrades
} // end class Summerise Grades
```

Comment: Where is the `}` for the class?

Comment: At the very bottom of the code

Comment: @CassyHiggins I tried running your `outputGrades` method and all 10 students were printed.

Comment: Hi Eran. I'm just getting the output line for student 10

Comment: @CassyHiggins I'm getting `               Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Average
Student  1      87      96      70    84.33 
Student  2      68      87      90    81.67 
Student  3      94     100      90    94.67 
Student  4     100      81      82    87.67 
Student  5      83      65      85    77.67 
Student  6      78      87      85    83.33 
Student  7      85      75      83    81.00 
Student  8      91      94     100    95.00 
Student  9      76      72      84    77.33 
Student 10      87      93      73    84.33 `

Comment: @CassyHiggins You must be running different code than what you posted in your question. I didn't change anything.

Comment: My output is: Student 10  87 93 73 84.33       No sign of the other students!

Comment: I'll try copying the code above and see how that goes

Comment: Still no luck with printing the other students details

Comment: Where are you running the code from?

Comment: Try refreshing the project. Maybe your bytecodes doesn't correspond to your code if you didn't refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I could reproduce this error. The problem is with `printf`. Edit the code like this, it will work even in textpad

```
for (int student = 0 ; student < grades.length ; student ++)
{
System.out.printf ("Student %2d", student + 1);

for ( int test : grades [ student ] ) // output student grades
    System.out.printf ("%8d", test );

// call method getAverage to calculate the student's average grade
// pass row of grades as the argument to getAverage
double average = getAverage (grades [ student ] ) ;
System.out.printf ("%9.2f \r", average );



/*Add this line */ 


       System.out.println ("");



} // end outer for
```

**OR**

as Tom suggested

```
for (int student = 0 ; student < grades.length ; student ++)
{
System.out.printf ("Student %2d", student + 1);

for ( int test : grades [ student ] ) // output student grades
    System.out.printf ("%8d", test );

// call method getAverage to calculate the student's average grade
// pass row of grades as the argument to getAverage
double average = getAverage (grades [ student ] ) ;

/* change this line */


System.out.printf ("%9.2f \n", average );



} // end outer for
```

And for your reference

Before:

```
bhargav@bhargav:~$ javac SummariseGrades.java 
bhargav@bhargav:~$ java SummariseGrades 
The grades are:

               Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Average
Student 10      87      93      73    84.33 
 Lowest grade is 65 
 Highest grade is 100 

Overall grade distribution:
00-09: 
10-19: 
20-29: 
30-39: 
40-49: 
50-59: 
60-69: **
70-79: ******
80-89: ************
90-99: *******
  100: ***
```

After :

```
bhargav@bhargav:~$ javac SummariseGrades.java 
bhargav@bhargav:~$ java SummariseGrades 
The grades are:

               Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Average
Student  1      87      96      70    84.33 
Student  2      68      87      90    81.67 
Student  3      94     100      90    94.67 
Student  4     100      81      82    87.67 
Student  5      83      65      85    77.67 
Student  6      78      87      85    83.33 
Student  7      85      75      83    81.00 
Student  8      91      94     100    95.00 
Student  9      76      72      84    77.33 
Student 10      87      93      73    84.33 

 Lowest grade is 65 
 Highest grade is 100 

Overall grade distribution:
00-09: 
10-19: 
20-29: 
30-39: 
40-49: 
50-59: 
60-69: **
70-79: ******
80-89: ************
90-99: *******
  100: ***
```

Comment: He don't need the println call. He just need to replace `\r` with `\n`.

Comment: @Tom Yeah ... I did not recognize that.

Comment: Doesn't matter that much. You've found the problem and provided a solution. That's what counts :).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and get this output:

```
The grades are:

           Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Average
Student  1      87      96      70    84.33 
Student  2      68      87      90    81.67 
Student  3      94     100      90    94.67 
Student  4     100      81      82    87.67 
Student  5      83      65      85    77.67 
Student  6      78      87      85    83.33 
Student  7      85      75      83    81.00 
Student  8      91      94     100    95.00 
Student  9      76      72      84    77.33 
Student 10      87      93      73    84.33 
Lowest grade is 65 
Highest grade is 100 

Overall grade distribution:
00-09: 
10-19: 
20-29: 
30-39: 
40-49: 
50-59: 
60-69: **
70-79: ******
80-89: ************
90-99: *******
100: ***
```

is this result what you want?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what Im looking for    For some reason I'm not getting any output for student 1 through 9.  Just got the output for student 10!

Comment: I've tried it in TextPad and it does not work properly... However it seems to work in Eclipse! I'm confused!